# RxJava не работает с файлами в io() потоке

Tags: java, rxjava

Суть проблемы такова: у меня есть `Observable` и `Subscriber`. `Observable` я пытаюсь запустить в `io()` потоке, так как он работает с файлами (не буду показывать код, он довольно большой, но не имеет значения), однако он ничего не делает:

```
    Observable<Double> creatingObservable = getCreatingObservable(image);
    Subscriber<Double> creatingSubscriber = getCreatingSubscriber();

    creatingObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(creatingSubscriber);
```

Если запускать код без `subscribeOn` - все прекрасно работает. Так в чем же проблема и как ее исправить?

---

P.S. У меня еще `System.out.println()` не работает. Проблема распространяется на все потоки `Scheduler'a`.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что проблема не в коде который вы решили не показывать? В приведенном вами коде проблеме взяться неоткуда так что она скорее всего внутри `getCreatingObservable`.

Comment: А по поводу `System.out.println()` - не надо это юзать на андройде. На андройде для логирования лучше использовать встроенный класс `Log`, или какие-нибудь сторонние либы типа [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)

Comment: @xkor, ой, `Android` я случайно дописал, по привычке. А проблема не в коде создания, я создавал его через обычный `create`. И на enSO помогли решить проблему, она была невероятно банальна...

Comment: @bukashka101, будет не лишним, если вы в вопрос/ответ добавите ссылки на en-SO)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что главный поток не дожидался окончания окончания выполнения `RxJava'вского` потока. В результате, `RxJava` даже не успевал "пискнуть" - от сюда никаких сообщений из `System.out.println()` и работы с файлами.

---

Решение подсказали тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993371/rxjava-doesnt-work-in-scheduler-io-thread